# Why do reads in MongoDB sometimes wait for lock?

Tags: mongodb

While using db.currentOp(), I sometimes see operations like:

```
{
        "opid" : 1238664,
        "active" : false,
        "lockType" : "read",
        "waitingForLock" : true,
        "op" : "query",
        .....
        "desc" : "conn"
    }
```

Why does a read operation need to wait for a lock? Is there a way to tell a query to ignore any pending writes and just go ahead and read anyway?

Comment: you certainly don't want the read a half written BSON object, do you?

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell a query ignore pending writes  because of mongodb indexes working in synchronous way. And this is by design.

For example indexes in [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) can work in async and sync way. So may be you need ravendb (if you on windows) ;)

> Why do reads in MongoDB sometimes wait for lock?

They are waiting for index rebuild.

Comment: Uh ... before you even recommend an alternative, you should ask whihc platform they're running. Looks like Raven only runs on Windows.

Comment: No you can run mongodb on linux with [mono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681106/why-do-reads-in-mongodb-sometimes-wait-for-lock/6681811#6681811). But yes, it is mostly project for the windows.

Comment: Right so when someone says I want to buy a 4x4 car you dont say "buy a honda civic."

Comment: It was just example to give an idea that some databases support it. But it was after i've answered NO on @Nicholas question. So i am not sure why you speaking about 'spaceships'.